# Failed to upgrade a chaincode in v2.1 Hyperledger Fabric Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I'm trying to upgrade my Hyperledger Fabric network from v1.4.7 to v2.1. Upgrading peers and orderers is done smoothly and already instantiated chaincodes work well. (Channel capabilities still remaining v1.x.) However, when I try to upgrade the new version of my chaincode, it keeps failed.

In v1.4.7, I built a server to install/instantiate/upgrade a chaincode using Fabric SDK v1.4.x. However, I found that all APIs related to installing/instantiating/upgrading a chaincode had been removed from Fabric SDK v2.1. So, as the doc said, I tried to upgrade a chaincode using `peer` CLI.

First, I packaged my chaincode using `peer lifecycle chaincode ...` command. At this time, I set `FABRIC_CFG_PATH` to a `core.yaml` in `fabric-samples` folder (I don't understand why I do this for only packaging a chaincode, but anyway I did what the doc said). And I set `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` to my admin user msp folder.

After I got my chaincode package, I connect to my first peer, `peer0.identity.bpl`, using `docker exec -it peer0.identity.bpl /bin/sh` command. My docker container doesn't open the port outside in the production mode, so I need to connect the container inside.

Then, I typed the following command and I got the error message:

```
/artifacts # peer lifecycle chaincode install identity_cc_v1.2.0.tar.gz

Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - Failed to authorize invocation due to failed ACL check: Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [The identity is not an admin under this MSP [BPLMSP]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP: [BPLMSP]]
```

So, I think I need some 'admin' identity, so I copied my admin msp folder to this peer. Then, I set `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` to this copied admin msp folder. Then I got:

```
/artifacts # export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/artifacts/org-admin/msp
/artifacts # peer lifecycle chaincode install identity_cc_v1.2.0.tar.gz

2020-05-26 07:21:47.020 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /artifacts/org-admin/msp: administrators must be declared when no admin ou classification is set
```

Now, I thought that maybe the OU setting had some problem. So, I disabled OU setting from the `config.yaml` file. But, I got the same error message again.

So, I changed `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` setting to original setting again, but now it said this is not an admin identity.

```
/artifacts # export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/artifacts/msp
/artifacts # peer lifecycle chaincode install identity_cc_v1.2.0.tar.gz

Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - Failed to authorize invocation due to failed ACL check: Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]
```

I understand. This identity is just a peer identity, not an admin identity. So, I tried to enroll admin in this peer, but this `fabric-peer` docker image doesn't contain `fabric-ca-client` binary. So, I thought I did something wrong and this is not the intended way.

At this point, how can I install and instantiate the new version of my chaincode?

Answer (score 0):

After I set OU config to admin msp that is copied to peer, every problem has been solved and installing/committing a chaincode works well.